# Getting scrollWheel to work... Implementing previous and forward gestures in WebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, xcode4.2

How can I implement the previous and forward swipe gestures in a webview... I've read through the Handling Trackpad Events guide, but I still can't get it right...

I've tried subclassing the WebView, the NSView, The NSWindow, but none of them work...  I can't even get it to call the scrollWheel Event... What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks

```
-- webView.h --


#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface swipeView : WebView
@end



-- webView.m --

- (void) awakeFromNib{
    [self setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];
    [self acceptsFirstResponder];
}


- (void) scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSLog(@"scroll");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you have your answer already, but here is what would have been mine:

Instead of calling the method

```
[self acceptsFirstResponder]
```

you have to implement it and return YES in your class.

```
- (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Happy coding!